# Return a part of a fraction in Calc Openoffice.

Tags: find, return, openoffice-calc, fractions

What I would like to do is have Calc OpenOffice return the value of the denominator of a cell.  I could do this with right or left, but then i'm constrained by the position.

Is there a way for me to find the denominator of a cell irrespective of the amount of digits in that cell?

So say i have three cells, A1, B1, C1. with values  1/3;  13/4;  1/1003, respectively
I want Calc to return 3; 4; 1003 in cells A2,B2,C2. The cells I want to get the values from are formatted as text, so as to preserve their original fraction form. The fractions represent error/total.

Is this possible? And how would I go about doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answers was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no-one responded and you did not report that you found the answer either:

Fraction data in cell A1:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("/";A1;1)-1)   = numerator
=MID(A1;FIND("/";A1;1)+1;9)  = denominator
```

Comment: Hey Robert Thanks for your suggestion, I had given up hope on the question. But I'm sorry to say Calc merely responds with #name?

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing else in the cell. I tried this myself and it worked like a charm. You could cut out the data and formula and send it to me to look at. See my e-mail in the profile.

Comment: HAHA, Whilst saving the file into a different format, The ODT format, to send to your email. The formula magically worked! Thanks such a lot!